# MySql why select 10.1.1.2 in like

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select ordering, dst from alist where ordering=2 and dst like '%10.1.1.2%';
+----------+---------------------+
| ordering | dst                 |
+----------+---------------------+
|        2 | 10.1.1.1-10.1.1.254 |
+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What is the issue , the result is valid and correct as per query

Comment: 10.1.1.1-10.1.1.254 <=== no 10.1.1.2

Comment: text between % matches sub string, which is correct here

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the literal path `10.1.1.2`, and not things like `10.1.1.254`, then you may try using `REGEXP` here:

```
SELECT ordering, dst
FROM alist
WHERE ordering = 2 AND dst REGEXP '[[:<:]]10.1.1.2[[:>:]]';
```

This corresponds to looking for the regex pattern `\b10.1.1.2\b`, i.e. there are word boundaries around your path.

The demo below correctly shows that there is no result set for your query as tested against the single row of sample data you provided.

### Demo

Comment: Huh?  I don't understand you

Comment: @neohwang : what is your expected output?

Comment: i want empty result.

Comment: @neohwang Did you even bother to [test my query](http://rextester.com/ZVO1945)?  It seems to be working.